# Efficient Memory Barriers

Tags: c++, linux

I have a multithreaded application, where each thread has a variable of integer type. These variables are incremented during execution of the program. At certain points in the code, a thread compares its counting variable with those of the other threads.

Now since, we know that threads running on multicore might execute out of order, a thread might not read the expected counter values of the other threads. To solve this problem, one way is to use atomic variable, such as std::atomic<> of C++11. However, performing a memory fence at each increment of counters will significantly slow down the program.

Now what I want to do is that when a thread is about to read other thread's counter, only then a memory fence is created and counters of all the threads are updated in the memory at that point. How can this be done in C++. I am using Linux and g++.

Comment: I think you really need to move towards a high speed IPC mechanism such as [Disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor-cpp/), concentrating on the barrier seems to be avoiding the more pertinent design issue.

Comment: No I'm not using it for IPC. However program needs to read the counters from other threads at some points.

Comment: I could have my concept of fences all wrong, but how will the (load?) fence in thread 1 help if there aren't any store fences in threads 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: fences are on a per-processing-unit basis, rather than any OS/support library concept such as thread or process. If you have threads running on multiple processing units, any fence calls only affect the processing unit on which the fence is invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++11 standard library includes support for fences in `<atomic>` with `std::atomic_thread_fence`.

Calling this invokes a full fence:

```
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

If you want to emit only an acquire or only a release fence, you can use `std:memory_order_acquire` and `std::memory_order_release` instead.

Comment: If C++11 isn't available, gcc provides the [`__sync_synchronize`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) memory barrier builtin.

Comment: @Metallic I'm not sure about C++11 but generally memory barriers work both at the compiler level and at the CPU level. At the compiler level they restrict how the load and stores can be re-ordered. At the CPU level, it depends on [the memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier#Low-level_architecture-specific_primitives).

Comment: @MetallicPriest: the compiler can implement the fences as it pleases, as long as it results in at least the required ordering. If you really want full control about those details, you will need to get out of standard C++ and resort to implementation-specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are x86 intrinsics that correspond to memory barriers that you can use yourself. The Windows header has a memory barrier macro, so you should be able to find something equivalent for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost::asio::strand for this exact purpose. Create a handler responsible for reading the counter. That handler can be called from multiple threads. Instead of directly calling the handler, wrap it inside a boost::asio::strand. This will ensure the handler can not be concurrently called by multiple threads.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html

I hope I understood the question right.

Comment: No I was not talking about timers. Just variables that are incremented in the code.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have a collectTimers() function in a higher level class that can ask each thread for its counter (via queue/msg).  This way updating timers are not delayed, but collecting timers is a bit slower.

This only works if you have some kind of communication mechanism between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

And why not having a "control" thread, to whom each thread reports its counter increments and ask for the values of others ?

It would make it very efficient and simple. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the signal-theft limit counter design in Secion 4.4.3 of http://mirror.nexcess.net/kernel.org/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.2011.08.28a.pdf

This kind of design can eliminate the atomic operations from the fastpath (incrementing the per-thread counter).  Whether the complexity is worth it is up to you to decide, of course.