# Can Rust compiler aggressively reorder statements like C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, rust, compiler-optimization

I just read [Enforcing statement order in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786547/enforcing-statement-order-in-c) and learned that C++ compliers are allowed to reorder

```
using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

auto t1 = Clock::now(); // Statement 1
foo();                  // Statement 2
auto t2 = Clock::now(); // Statement 3

auto elapsedTime = t2 - t1;
```

into

```
using Clock=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

foo();                  // Statement 2
auto t1 = Clock::now(); // Statement 1
auto t2 = Clock::now(); // Statement 3

auto elapsedTime = t2 - t1;
```

And one need to use something like

```
template <class T>
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline void DoNotOptimize(const T &value) {
  asm volatile("" : "+m"(const_cast<T &>(value)));
}
```

to help with ensuring the order. Is the Rust compiler allowed to do the same thing? If not, what rules of Rust prevent that? If yes, what is the workaround?

Comment: "into" - no, they don't reorder in such way.

Comment: @273K are there particular Rust rules guaranteeing that?

Comment: I mean neither C++ nor Rust reorder in such way. They don't reorder function calls in different statements. See [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), the rule 10).

Comment: @273K If the compiler decided to inline the foo() function call, it might happen. See this example:https://godbolt.org/z/vfv8aMEMM, where the content of the function call `add ebx, ebx` was moved before the two calls to `std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()`.

Comment: @273K, the post I linked to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786547/enforcing-statement-order-in-c) also explained why a compliant C++ compiler might actually do that. And also see this example: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0342r0.html

Comment: It does not reorder https://godbolt.org/z/c44vv41sb Perhaps, it was a compiler defect not conforming the Order of evaluation.

Comment: @Roun: In the linked examples, the compiler only reorders stuff **after** having inlined the function.  But when the compiler has no knowledge of the internals of `foo()` (so it can't inline), it also can't reorder.

Comment: You can use [compiler_fence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/fn.compiler_fence.html) to prevent it from reordering operations. However this is only useful in very minor edge cases.

Comment: That inline asm is lacking a `"memory"` clobber so it won't stop reordering of ops on a local variable wrt. non-inline function calls.  Unless maybe forcing a store/reload with a `"+m"` instead of `"+r"` makes it think the address has escaped the function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are allowed. But there is easier workaround than using inline assembly: [`std::hint::black_box()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/hint/fn.black_box.html), that essentially fills the role of `DoNotOptimize()` in your C++ code.

Note that this is not a guarantee, just a hint (it is very hard to provide such guarantee generically, and I don't think your `DoNotOptimize()` guarantees that either).